# Binding error while integrating flutter module in android app

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

setBinding(new Binding([gradle:this]))

The Binding after new shown error in android studio, am trying to import things that shown in suggestion but it cant work,

The error it show is "Cannot resolve symbol 'Binding'". Anyone can you help me out?

Answer (score -1):

There is a step by step procedure for binding in `flutter.dev`
Follow this link:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup

Answer (score -1):

rebuild gradle by run this command in terminal

$ gradlew init

After running this command, some questions will appear to you, choose the answer that matches your project "like this"

Select type of project to generate:
1: basic
2: application
3: library
4: Gradle plugin
Enter selection (default: basic) [1..4] 2

Select implementation language:
1: C++
2: Groovy
3: Java
4: Kotlin
5: Scala
6: Swift
Enter selection (default: Java) [1..6] 4

Split functionality across multiple subprojects?:
1: no - only one application project
2: yes - application and library projects
Enter selection (default: no - only one application project) [1..2] 2

Select build script DSL:
1: Groovy
2: Kotlin
Enter selection (default: Kotlin) [1..2] 2

Generate build using new APIs and behavior (some features may change in the next minor release)? (default: no) [yes, no] yes
Project name (default: PrimaMobile-master): "click enter"
Source package (default: PrimaMobile.master): "click enter"

Now wait for complete the gradle rebuilding

it's work for me